# Use matplotlib: plot error bars on two y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes, errorbar

I'd like to plot a series with x and y error bars, then plot a second series with x and y error bars on a second y axis all on the same subplot. Can this be done with matplotlib?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.errorbar(voltage, dP, xerr=voltageU, yerr=dPU)
ax2 = plt.errorbar(voltage, current, xerr=voltageU, yerr=currentU)
plt.show()
```

Basically, I'd like to put ax2 on a second axis and have the scale on the right side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`twinx()` is your friend for adding a secondary y-axis, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

pl.figure()

ax1 = pl.gca()
ax1.errorbar(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), xerr=np.random.random(10), yerr=np.random.random(10), color='g')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.errorbar(np.arange(10), np.arange(10)+5, xerr=np.random.random(10), yerr=np.random.random(10), color='r')
```

There is not a lot of [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=twinx#matplotlib.pyplot.twinx) except for:

> matplotlib.pyplot.twinx(ax=None)
>   Make a second axes that shares the x-axis. The new axes will overlay ax (or the current axes if ax is None). The ticks for ax2 will be placed on the right, and the ax2 instance is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to share the x-axis, but thank you @Bart you saved me!
The simple solution is use `twiny` instead of `twinx`

```
ax1.errorbar(layers, scores_means[str(epoch)][h,:],np.array(scores_stds[str(epoch)][h,:]))

# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_xlabel('depth', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('x', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.errorbar(hidden_dim, scores_means[str(epoch)][:,l], np.array(scores_stds[str(epoch)][:,l]))
ax2.set_xlabel('width', color='r')
ax2.tick_params('x', colors='r')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```